# Simpsons rule for $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Approximate the result of the following integral with simpsons rule:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Simpsons rule suggests $$\int_a^b f(x)dx \sim \frac{b-a}{6n}[f(a)+4f(x_1)+2(x_2) + \cdots + 4f(x_{2n-1})+f(b)]$$

For n = 5,

I have the following:

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2} \sim \frac{1}{30}[0+4\frac{1}{1+(\frac{1}{30})^2}+2\frac{1}{1+(\frac{2}{30})^2}+4\frac{1}{1+(\frac{3}{30})^2}+2\frac{1}{1+(\frac{4}{30})^2}] + 4\frac{1}{1+(\frac{5}{30})^2} + 1$$

However, this does not produce the desired result.

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: If I still know how to read, for $n=5$ you should have nine points $x_j$ (watever they are), plus $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=\frac12$.

Comment: The stated value of the integral is wrong. Moreover the simpson's *approximation* will never give you the right answer in this situation, only something close to it

Comment: Joe, actually $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\big[\arctan x\big]_0^1=\frac{\pi}4\,.$$